C++ cout print order compared to C printf
I have two "equivalent" programs in C and in C++ that have different outputs.
They should print step by step all the powers of a "base" between 0 and "exp"
test.c is:
#include <stdio.h>  

int power(int b, int e) {  
    int p = 1;  
    for (int i = 0; i < e; i++) {  
        printf("%d^%d = %d\n", b, i, p);  
        p = p * b;  
    }  
    return p;  
}  

int main() {  
    int base = 2, exp = 3;  
    printf("%d^%d = %d\n", base, exp, power(base, exp));  
    return 0;  
}

output:
2^0 = 1  
2^1 = 2  
2^2 = 4  
2^3 = 8  

test.cpp is:
#include <iostream>  

using namespace std;  

int power(int b, int e) {  
    int p = 1;  
    for (int i = 0; i < e; i++) {  
        cout << b << "^" << i << " = " << p << endl;  
        p = p * b;  
    }  
    return p;  
}  

int main() {  
    int base = 2, exp = 3;  
    cout << base << "^" << exp << " = " << power(base, exp) << endl;  
    return 0;  
} 

output:
2^3 = 2^0 = 1  
2^1 = 2  
2^2 = 4  
8  

Can anybody please tell me why does this happen?
Why does the "cout" print the first part before executing the function?

printf is a function call, it needs to evaluate all of its arguments before it can start printing. cout is a chain of operators, it's equivalent to calling a different function for each object you print. One solution would be to change the second example to perform all the printing in its own function, passing all the values to print as arguments, just like you do in the first example. Another is to call power and store the result in a variable before you start printing.

For a more "Fair" comparisson in C++ use std::format (C++20) or std::print (C++23). If you're on an earlier version of C++ use the fmt/format library

This is how operator << works. First one is evaluated it returns reference to std::cout then next operator << is evaluated and so one. So this C++ code is equivalent to:
int main()
{
    int base = 2, exp = 3;
    cout << base; 
    cout << "^"; 
    cout << exp; 
    cout << " = "; 
    cout << power(base, exp); 
    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}

So main prints something before calling power and prints something after calling power. Here is some tool which expands C/C++ expressions which shows this to some extent.
In C code all arguments must be evaluated first before main can print, so power must finish printing before printing in main can be done.
Note C++23 has introduced std::print which is type safe as std::cout and behaves like printf in this scenario:
#include <print>

int power(int b, int e)
{
    int p = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < e; i++) {
        std::print("{}^{} = {}\n", b, i, p);
        p = p * b;
    }
    return p;
}

int main()
{
    int base = 2, exp = 3;
    std::print("{}^{} = {}\n", base, exp, power(base, exp));
    return 0;
}

https://godbolt.org/z/vEeMP5nbP

cout is evaluated left-to-right. It simply prints everything it sees, when it sees it. So, in your case, your function is called only after printing the first part of the line.
printf, on the other hand, needs to evaluate everything to fill itself in. So, it runs your function first and then prints.
If you want to get this behavior in C++, it probably makes the most sense to define your output as a string, fill in your output, and then print that all at once, such as:
#include <iostream>

#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int power(int b, int e) {
  int p = 1;
  for (int i = 0; i < e; i++) {
    cout << b << "^" << i << " = " << p << endl;
    p = p * b;
  }
  return p;
}

int main() {
  stringstream out;
  int base = 2, exp = 3;
  out << base << "^" << exp << " = " << power(base, exp);
  cout << out.str() << endl;
  return 0;
}

This code has the exact same output as your C code.

cout and printf are not the issues here. << and function call semantics are.

Fair, that's a simplification error on my part. << is used with cout, though, so I'd say that my answer is maybe imprecise rather than inaccurate. That said, looks like Marek R posted a good (more precise) answer after I did, so probably best to go with that one.
